# Rails 3 + Omniauth: pass extra params to the api server (DoorKeeper)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, oauth

I am creating an API for my application. On one side, there is the API server (and the main app) and on the other, the client. The sever uses DoorKeeper to secure the API using OAuth 2.0 (basically turning the main app into an OAuth 2.0 provider) and the client is using OmniAuth with a custom strategy for my app.

The main app uses multitenancy using subdomains; so every client has its own subdomain. There is also a `oauth` subdomain that is routed to the DoorKeeper interface.

When a user clicks on the "Log in with my app" link, he gets redireced to the oauth subdomain. If he is not logged in to the main app, he needs to get redirected to the login page **under the correct subdomain**. So I need to pass the client's account name to the server so that DoorKeeper knows to which subdomain to redirect to.

How can I achieve that please?

I've researched on the subject and found out how to pass to OmniAuth params that will get passed to the callback action. Will those params be available to the server?

**EDIT**: I am not using Devise!

**EDIT 2**: Here is some code.

Client app session controller create action (log in with my app)

```
def set_client
  self.current_client = Client.find(params[:client][:name])
  redirect_to "/auth/catapult?client=#{self.current_client.account_name}"
end
```

As you can see, I append the client param to the OmniAuth route, but this param is not passed to the server app (DoorKeeper), so I have no idea where to redirect to on the server app.

DoorKeeper config

```
resource_owner_authenticator do
  p params
  User.find_by_id(session[:user_id]) || redirect_to(log_in_path)
end
```

In the redirect above, I need to specify the client's account name as subdomain, but I don't have this info (client's account name) since the params hash does't contain the client's account name that I passed (the client param)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out how to fix my problem. I had to dig in deeper into the OmniAuth source code. what I had to do is override the `request_phase` method in my custom strategy as follow:

```
def request_phase
  redirect client.auth_code.authorize_url({:redirect_uri => callback_url, :catapult_client => request.params["client"]}.merge(authorize_params))
end
```

Where `:catapult_client` is, add any extra params you want to pass and it just works!

Comment: How can we handle the same thing for token_url? I have to provide different token_url based on policy name. authorize_url can be provided with different value based on policy in the request_phase method. Once authorization is done, token_url has to be provided with the same policy name to get the token. Any idea how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to pass the place-to-redirect-to-after-authenticating-successfully as a query param when they are redirected to the login page, so it's there as part of the GET request's querystring. Store it, and on a successful auth, redirect them there. You don't need to involve this data in the OAuth process at all.

Of course, I'm assuming that they all *start* at their subdomain too.

---

Edit:

> When a user clicks on the "Log in with my app" link, he gets redireced to the oauth subdomain.

- *Assuming* the user starts at `mysubdomain.yourapp.com`, they click on the "Log in with my app" link.
- The link also contains a query parameter with the subdomain in it, so `oauth.yourapp.com?redirect=mysubdomain.yourapp.com` (or just `oauth.yourapp.com?redirect=mysubdomain`)
- The user arrives at oauth.yourapp.com. The app stores the query parameter. The user puts in their details or is redirected to a service…
- The OAuth process is finished, the user has been authenticated.
- Redirect the user back to the `redirect` parameter stored earlier.

This is how I do it, just not with Rails, but I don't see why you couldn't use this process with *any* framework. This, as I mentioned, depends on the user starting on the correct subdomain.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your answer... I added some code to make the question clearer.

Comment: @AzizLight I added more explanation. It'll either answer you question or prompt more info from you :)

Comment: Basically the user starts under no subdomain, the client app is a different app (typically it can be a mobile app, it just happens that it's another Rails app), what I need to do, is make omniauth pass the extra param to doorkeeper. So basically I can't use your method because I am not doing the GET request myself, OmniAuth is...

Comment: @AzizLight Ok, I'll leave this up in case anyone else finds it useful, and I'll have a look at Doorkeeper later to see if I can help you with this.